# Invoke WebAPI service asynchronously from WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I have a WPF application which requires to call a .NET WEBPI asynchronous. The service consists of a Heavy job so that moved to service side for performance reason. User is not required to get response from the service. So the operation should not prevent the user to continue with the application.

How do I call a RESTful service from WPF asynchronously? I am using .NET 4.0 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really all you are trying to achieve is making the call not on the UI thread.
If you are not interested in knowing when the work is complete, you can use a number of different ways to simply fire and forget a task.

Start a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourMethod())
```

Use the [Threadpool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MethodWrapper))
```

Use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)